# Increment a date in a Struts

Tags: date, struts2

I don't even know if this is possible, but I am attempting to compare two dates in a strut. I am attempting to check if `date1` is equal to `date2 + 1`.

Example code:

```
<s:if test="%{beginDate.equal(endDate+1)}">
  ...
</s:if>
```

Is there a way to increment the `endDate` to compare them?

Comment: Use any date-math library?

Comment: And how you would do that in java class?

Answer (score 0):

The following is more of a workaround as it requires a change in your action class as well as your JSP file.  Also, it will require you to apply a `SimpleDateFormat` to your date so that only the day, month and year are used in your comparison - I'm assuming you do not want to compare hours, minutes, seconds as your check would be *very* exact.

Change `endDate` to `formattedEndDate` and `beginDate` to `formattedBeginDate` in your JSP:

```
<s:if test="%{formattedBeginDate.equal(formattedEndDate)}">
...
</s:if>
```

In your action class handle formatting the dates to only use year, month and day.  Also handle incrementing the end date:

```
//Specified in your member variable declarations.
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
...

public Date getFormattedEndDate() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(this.getEndDate());
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); //minus number would decrement the days
    return format.parse(cal.getTime());
}

public Date getFormattedBeginDate() {
    return format.parse(this.getBeginDate());
}
```

This is just one way of doing it. You can of course rename the methods to whatever makes sense to you.

**Another alternative**
A simpler approach may be to just create a method in your action class that does this date comparison for you:

```
public Date isDatesOk() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(this.getEndDate());
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); //minus number would decrement the days
    Date formattedEndDate = format.parse(cal.getTime());

    cal.setTime(this.getBeginDate());
    Date formattedBeginDate = format.parse(cal.getTime());

    return formattedEndDate.equals(formattedBeginDate);
}
```

And for your JSP:

```
<s:if test="${datesOk}">
...
</s:if>
```

Comment: @Alexksandr M If we did not format the date, then we would be comparing not only year, month and day, but also hour, minute, second, millisecond. I'm assuming in my answer that you do not want to only compare the year, month and day.

Comment: It is easy to set other values to 0 than parse a date.

Comment: I would agree that parsing dates is not the easiest thing, but the above are two options that should work for you. If you want to somehow use a Math API for this, I'm sure it is doable, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Personally I would do it right in JSP. But anyway OP has not stated that he wants to compare dates w/o minutes, seconds... and using `cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);` etc. would be faster.

Comment: You are correct - OP has not stated that, it was an assumption that can easily be removed from the above code by simply removing the date formatting. If you are suggesting using cal.set(...) then please go ahead and post that as a possible answer.